# How can I make a vertical UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, sdk, toolbar

How can I make a vertical UIToolbar?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want your UIBarButtonItems to maintain their orientation relative to the tool bar, or do you want them to be perpendicular to the orientation to the tool bar?

Comment: the items should be orderd vertically but the  items iteself should be horizontal. (i should read it without turning the device)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
#define M_PI 3.141

UIToolbar *tool;

tool.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 270.0/180*M_PI);
```

Answer (score 4):

Subclass UIToolbar and do the following:

```
CGFloat DegreesToRadian(CGFloat degrees)
{
    return ((M_PI * (degrees))/ 180.0);
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadian(90));
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView * subView in self.subviews) 
    {
        if(!CGRectEqualToRect(subView.bounds, self.bounds))
            subView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadian(-90));
    }
}
```