# UIToolbar items don't move when frame is updated

Tags: ios, rotation, uitoolbar

Synopsis: My toolbar items are not moving with the UIToolbar when the frame is changed.

Details:
I have a UIToolbar that I programmatically set up at the bottom of the screen in portrait mode.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 50, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 50);
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame: frame];
//.... create a NSArray of toolbar items called toolbarItems 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar setItems:toolbarItems];
```

When the screen is rotated to landscape mode I change the frame so that it sits on one side (in this case, the left side):

```
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
```

The toolbar frame moves just fine, but the button items are still displayed at the bottom of the screen where they were in portrait mode.

Is there a way to tell the toolbar to update its contents? I have also tried removing and recreating the toolbar and adding new items, but this still happens.

Comment: Does `[toolbar setNeedsLayout]` fix it?

Comment: You seem to be resizing the toolbar to be vertical down the left side, correct? I don't think a toolbar is designed to work in such a layout.

Comment: You should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570940/how-can-i-make-a-vertical-uitoolbar

Comment: @maddy the vertical bar solution rotates the items, but not the frame :/.

Comment: Actually, that does work.. the problem was that the screen bounds are still in portrait mode, so the height of the toolbar was bigger than the screen and hiding the buttons.